# Jun Shao's Randomized Decision Rule

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics

According to Mathematical Statistics by Shao, a randomized decision rule is a function is $\delta$ on $ \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{F}_A$, where $\mathcal{F}_A$ is a sigma algebra, such that for every $ A \in \mathcal{F}_A$ $\delta(\cdot, A) $ is a borel function, and for every $x \in \mathcal{X}$ $\delta(x,\cdot)$ is a a probability measure on $(\mathbb{A}, \mathcal{A})$.

Let $\delta_1(t,A) = E(\delta_0(X,A)|T=t)$ be a randomized decision rule, depending only on $T$, which is a sufficient statistic for $P \in \mathcal{P}$.

Why do we have
$$E\left(\int_A L(P,a) d\delta_1(X,a)\right) = E\left(E\left( \int_A L(P,a) d\delta_0(X,a) \mid  T \right)\right)?$$

This is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4647072/understanding-proposition-2-2-in-jun-shaos-mathematical-statistics), but the answer to that question, doesn't clarify my doubt, without a deep reformulation.

Comment: Given probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and  $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}$ contained in $\mathcal{F}$, we have that $E[X]=E[ E\big[X|\mathcal{A}]\big]$ for all integrable measurable function $X$.

Comment: @Mittens, hum... but the RHS is written with respect to $\delta_0$, not $\delta_1$. I think the justification should be somewhat different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the background, we have a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F})$ and a population $\mathcal{P}$ (a family of probability measures on $(\Omega,\mathscr{F})$).

Suppose $X:(\Omega,\mathscr{F})\rightarrow(\mathbb{X},\mathcal{F})$ be a random variable. Any given statistic $T$ with values on some space $\mathbb{T}$ can be viewed as a measurable function $T:(\Omega,\mathscr{F})\rightarrow(\mathbb{T},\mathcal{T})$ can be seen as a random variable on $(\Omega,\mathscr{F})$.

The randomized decision $\delta_0$ is a **stochastic kernel** from $(\mathbb{X},\mathcal{F})$ to $(\mathbb{A},\mathcal{A})$. That is, for $x\in \mathbb{X}$ fixed, $\delta(x,\cdot)$ is a (probability) measure on $(\mathbb{A},\mathcal{A})$, and for each $A\in\mathcal{A}$, $\delta(\cdot,A)$ is an $\mathcal{F}$-measurable function. Standard integration arguments (start with simple functions, extend to nonnegative measurable functions via monotone convergence, etc) imply that for any bounded measurable function $f:(\mathbb{A},\mathcal{A})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,
$$x\mapsto(\delta_0f)(x)=\int_Af(a)\delta_0(x,da)$$
is a measurable function on $(\mathbb{X},\mathcal{F})$ and so,
$$\omega\mapsto(\delta_0f)(X(\omega))$$
is a measurable function on $(\Omega,\mathscr{F})$. In particular,
$$h_f:\omega\mapsto\delta_0f(X(\omega))=\int_{\mathbb{A}}f(a)\delta_0(X(\omega),da)$$
is a measurable function on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$. It then makes sense to consider the conditional expectation
$$\mathbb{E}[h_f|T]:=\mathbb{E}[h_f|\sigma(T)]$$
Further inspection of this relation shows that the conditioning defined a stochastic kernel $\delta_1$ from $(\Omega,\sigma(T))$ to $(\mathbb{A},\mathcal{A})$ given by
$$\delta_1f (\cdot)=\mathbb{E}\big[h_f|\sigma(T)\big](\cdot)=\mathbb{E}\Big[\int_{\mathbb{A}} f(a)\delta_0(X,da)|\sigma(T)\Big](\cdot)$$
This of course holds if $(\mathbb{T},\mathcal{T})$ is a *nice* space, for example a Polish space (in many applications $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\mathcal{T}$ is the corresponding Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Consequently

$$\mathbb{E}\big[\delta_1f\big]=\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}\big[\int_{\mathbb{A}}f(a)\,d_0(X,da)\,|\sigma(T)\big]\Big]$$

where the identity follows from well known properties of the conditional expectation operator: $E[Y]=E\big[E[Y|\mathcal{G}]\big]$ for any integral random variable $Y$ and sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}\subset\mathscr{F}$.

In the context of the topic at hand, $f(a)=L(P, a)$, and $\mathbb{E}$ is expectation with respect to the probability measure $P$.

Comment: Many thanks! I think I got it, now. I hadn't realized that a randomized decision rule could be seen as a stochastic kernel, and that it made sense to define $\delta(x,A) f = \int_A f (a) \delta(x,da) $.